# MATLAB shuffling structure array

Tags: matlab, structure, swap, shuffle

I have 2 functions, 1 that creates a deck of 52 cards and puts them in order. The other function shuffles the cards. I have created the deck and it is in order. The structure has attributes suit and number I'm having trouble shuffling it. I need to create two random integers that range from 1 to the number of cards in our deck. Using those two values, we swap the cards at those indices. Repeat this swapping process a large (~1000) number of times. I can't use any of MATLAB's functions like swap or randperm.

Here is my function that takes in a structure array and returns a structure array of the shuffled cards:

```
function shuffle(input)

r=randi(1,52)
s=randi(1,52)
for index=1:52
temp=input(r).number;
input(r).number=input(s).number;
input(s).number=temp;
end;
```

Comment: Ok... so in your previous question, you weren't allowed to use `randperm`, but you can use `randi`?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work for the first swap. Are you getting incorrect results?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you're only swapping the number and not the suit, but that shouldn't be too hard to fix, right?

Comment: Ya I can use randi(). I have to generate to random numbers and use those to swap the cards

Comment: I can also see that I used randi() wrong. To create a random integer between 1 and 52 it would be randi(52)

Comment: So what part do you need help with? You don't seem to have a specific question.

Comment: The problem with `randi` is that it doesn't give you unique values each time.  If you want to shuffle cards, you have to generate 52 random **and unique** integers.  If all you can use is `randi`, you can't shuffle your cards successfully.

Comment: I have to " create two random integers that range from 1 to the number of cards in our deck. Using those two values, we swap the cards at those indices. Repeat this swapping process a large (~1000) number of times. "

Comment: @WilliamDiuguid That is a statement, not a question.

Comment: @rayryeng But if you generate 1000 (not necessarily unique) numbers from 1-52, you're pretty likely to hit them all.

Comment: @beaker that's true.... but there is still a possibility where it won't :D

Comment: @rayryeng Only randomly ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have the swap figured out but need to include both number and suit. Also, you don't want to iterate through the 52 cards, you want to simply swap 2 cards ~1000 times. So add another input `N` for the number of times you want to swap during the shuffle, then use a for loop accordingly. Also, you need to have the function output the shuffled deck (in C++ the array would be passed by reference and you wouldn't need an output, but I don't think MATLAB will do that).

This should do the trick:

```
function output = shuffle(input, N)

% swap two cards N times
for i = 1:N
    % pick two random cards each time
    r = randi(52);
    s = randi(52);

    % store one in temporary variables
    tempNum = input(r).number;
    tempSuit = input(r).suit;

    % swap 
    input(r).number = input(s).number;
    input(r).suit = input(s).suit;
    input(s).number = tempNum;
    input(s).suit = tempSuit;
end

output = input;
```

Comment: If you use `function input = shuffle(input, N)` you won't need `output = input;`.

Comment: True, I prefer to see it with a new name but using the same variable does save memory.

Comment: It was only in response to *(in C++ the array would be passed by reference and you wouldn't need an output, but I don't think MATLAB will do that).*

Comment: Ah yes, that would give you the same behaviour. I'm sure I've made a few functions like that in the past.